# Replace categories of nominal variable by weight of evidence

Tags: python, list

I had a question about replacing the categorical values of a nominal variable with their evidence of weight. I have calculated the evidence of weight succesfully, but i fail to  replace the categorical values by their respective evidence of weight.

This is my code:

```
for i in range (26962):
    for j in range (202):
        if INDUSTRY_CD_3_preprocessing[i] == woe_INDUSTRY_CD_3[0]['Value'][j]:
            INDUSTRY_CD_3_preprocessing[i] = woe_INDUSTRY_CD_3[0]['WoE'][j]
```

INDUSTRY_CD_3_preprocessing is a pandas series containing the values of a nominal variable. woe_INDUSTRY_CD_3 is a tuple containing in index 0 a dataframe with columns **Value** for the different values of the categorical variable and **WoE** for the corresponding evidence of weight.
The nominal variable has 202 unique values and the INDUSTRY_CD_3_preprocessing ontains 26962 values of the nominal variable

Comment: Do you get an error when running this? What happens to the list you are trying to change?

Comment: Currently, the nominal values don't change at all...

Comment: Some nice print statements could help debug this, if you add a `print(i, j)` to the code if the `if` statement passes, does anything print? If not you may not have the data you think?

Comment: I replaced my code: for i in range (26962):
    for i in range (202):
        if INDUSTRY_CD_3_preprocessing[i] == woe_INDUSTRY_CD_3[0]['Value'][j]:
            #INDUSTRY_CD_3_preprocessing[i] = woe_INDUSTRY_CD_3[0]['WoE'][j]
            print(INDUSTRY_CD_3_preprocessing[i])`

Comment: Did that print anything?

Comment: It gave KeyError 26962

Comment: This suggests that your `Value` or `WoE` columns are not lists but are dictionaries

Comment: Found the solution, thanks for the thinking!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question:

You have to convert the pandas series to a float, because the evidences of weight are also floats! When you dindn't do this, you get a list containing 1's 0's and other integers.